# Supply power to more than 4 SCSI devices?

Tags: scsi, power-supply-unit

I was wondering, essentially I wanted to pool 4-10 SCSI drives in to a single computer, but of course only have a limited amount of 12v power cables to go in to them. What would be the proper way to deal with this, an external power supply unit, or just distributing the drives between systems through internal networking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your power supply is large enough to support the number of drives you want to put in your system, you have several options:

- Install one or more [multi-bay disk trays](http://www.supermicro.com/products/accessories/mobilerack/CSE-M35T-1.cfm), which typically power several disks using one molex connector.
- Use [splitters](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00173I5WE) to increase the number of available plugs in your case.

Comment: Very informative, I have much to learn it seems, Thank you!